# Why use Apache Sling for JCR?

Tags: apache, adobe, sling

From a documentation of AEM following is said:

```
AEM is built using Apache Sling, a web application framework based on REST principles 
that  provides  easy  development  of  content-oriented  applications.
```

Why was AEM created with Apache Sling (which uses HTTP) and not with Jackrabbit or CRX (without HTTP)?

I can understand its use if the content repository is on another machine, as in the case where you use the Run Mode author and the resources are on another machine, but I do not understand why it is used for the realization of AEM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the following reasons and more:

- it abstracts away the JCR API, which is quite cumbersome
- an JCR implementation is basically just an OSGI component running in Felix (probably also other OSGI runtime) and Sling just grabs the data from it. JackRabbit itself, or OAK, could both be replaced by different persistence layers. Sling provides APIs to access other data stores as well using its own APIs.
- Sling lets you abstract away the representation of content from its internal structure very easily.
- it provides a consistent component api, which can be used to implement real applications on top of JCR while being more productive. It basically follows from #2
- HTTP (as used used by Sling) is an interface providing various ways to deliver content and is easier to embed in a complex network infrastructure, as the web runs on it.

You don't need Sling but it clearly makes you more productive, when you are building web applications as it is a flexible representation layer on top.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer. Last reason is really interesting. What I also understood is that resources can have a different representation, this is due to Sling or the HTTP protocol? Is this another reason to use REST?

Comment: No, it is because auf the Sling engine. The `sling:resourceType` determines the default rendering. Using extensions and selectors, you can change the state of the representation. Using component inheritance and composition ... you have a lot of more possibilities. REST comes into play when you address the resources (GET) or modify (POST/PUT) resources. Locating a resource though plays very well with HTTP in the AEM context, since URIs are meant to be uniform (GET parameters are usually avoided).

Comment: Is it not for REST architecture that different representations can be obtained? such as is said here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Resource_identification_in_requests

Comment: You should not conflate the conceptual architecture of REST with the actual implementation. While the REST approach encourages different representations, not system providing a RESTful API is bound to this constraint. It might be wise to follow the architectural proposal, but an implementation does not have to. Sling provides various ways to follow the RESTful design and architecture out of the box though.

Comment: Ah ok now I understand it. It comes  I had that doubt when you said "REST comes into play ...". Thanks again.

Comment: The my dubt not comes by your answer, but for my misunderstanding of concept.